# Redirecting URLS from page document text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, href, userscripts

So i am working on a Userscript and there is one major step i'm trying to find the easiest resolve with since i am very new to Javascript coding...I'm trying to perform/code a function that will open a specified URL:

EXAMPLE: Homepage ("http://www.EXAMPLE.com")
(page can be opened as 'Window.open' = Blank, or _self);

...when the parent or (current) URL that is open
EXAMPLE: innner.href = ("www.EXAMPLE.com/new/01262016/blah/blah/blah");

...has a text on the HTML documnt page that reads:
EXAMPLE TEXT from page ("www.EXAMPLE.com/new/01262016/blah/blah/blah");: 
"this is the end of the page, please refresh to return back to homepage"

(TEXT: not the real keyword, but want to use phase as a detection for a setTimeout function to return back to home.)

Any help will be much appreicated, you guys are veryinformative here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the gist of you question.  It is a straighforward, though quite intensive, task to scan the entire text content of a page for specific keywords with JavaScript.  However, if the keywords appear more than once (on multiple pages that should not redirect) then your users will get undesirable results.

A simple solution would be to add a `class="last-page"` attribute to the `body`-tag of the final page and run a function that checks for this.  Something like....

**HTML**

```
<body class="last-page"><!--page content--></body>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = function() {
   var interval = 5000; // five seconds
   if (document.body.classList.contains('last-page')) {
     setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.assign('http://the-next-page.com/');
      }, interval);
  }
};
```

Alternatively, if you have the ability to wrap the specified text in a uniquely identified `html`-tag, such as...

```
<span id="last-page">EXAMPLE TEXT</span>
```

...then the presence of this tag can be checked on each page load - similar to the function above:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var interval = 5000;
  if (document.getElementById('last-page') {
    setTimeout(/* code as before */);
  }
};
```

Yet another solution is to check the page URL against a variable...

```
window.onload = function() {
  var finalURL = 'http://the-last-page.com/blah/...';
  if (window.location === finalURL) {
    /* same as before */
  }
};
```

If this kind of thing is not an option please leave a comment and I'll add a function that gathers a pages entire text content and compares adjacent words to a pre-defined set of keys.

Comment: hahah yes thank you so very much. I usually give my post a 24windows, this is the first i am reading this now and will be sure the make the corrections

Comment: Ok So it didnt work... any of them. I think its because its not a .js that i am coding, but a userscript. my coding on my userscript starts as:

==UserScript===
Window.open =
var urlsToLoad  = [
setTimeout =
Function to GoToNextURL

Comment: it wont let me edit my post: here is the Full post:

Ok So it didnt work... any of them. I think its because its not a .js that i am coding, but a userscript. my coding on my userscript starts as:
@info for Userscript
==UserScript===
Window.open =
var urlsToLoad  = [
setTimeout =
Function to GoToNextURL

it doesnt recognize <body>, <class>, or <span ID>. the only thing that works is what you added in the JS part of your example, the HTML part causes errors in Inspect mode.

Comment: is there a way to make it recognizable? I can gladly send you my userscript to look over or set up a Teamviewer meeting, as i am new to coding.

Comment: @Bagnar what platform are you using for your pages?

Comment: I am using Userscipts for the coding platform. Still not working NEED HELP PLZ